# South django.db.utils.IntegrityError: django_content_type.name may not be NULL while running unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, nose, django-south

I'm getting this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: django_content_type.name may not be NULL` while running tests via `nosetest`.

I've done everything as told in south tutorial - initial migration, fake migration etc.
Running site normally via `runserver` command works like charm, but while using `test` command - above error.

Also, In my development enviroment I'm using `sqlite` database and I'm using django-nose as test runner (at the very end of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I've managed to solve the problem on my own.

Seems to me that there is a problem integrating south, nose and in-memory db which is created by the django test command.

All I had to do is to define TEST_NAME in my developement settings - like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'database.sqlite',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_database.sqlite',
    }
}
```

That's it :)